# How to shift a database field entry to the right

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL Database.

In it's table is a field called 'itm_name'

I'm trying to retrieve several bits of data from this field.

However, there is some non-uniformity due to irregular whitespaces and alignment.

Is it possible to shift some of the entries to the right and replace the shifted areas with WhiteSpace?

For Example:

```
From:

CHOCOABLOC        (CH Egg.  |

To:

    CHOCOABLOC          (CH Egg.  |
```

Comment: You mean like `SPACE(2) || itm_name`

Comment: well, cant you trim the whitespaces on retrieving the data instead of adding it to values...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but this seems like the worst possible way to get there.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? It sounds very much like a display issue and the database shouldn't be concerned with display issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update your_table
set your_column = concat('  ', your_column)
where substring(your_column, 1, 2) != '  '
```